# I'm trying to use a functional IIF statement within a JOIN statment

Tags: reporting-services, iif

I want to blend these two commands into one…

1. This statement joins all agency.value that have been selected and works fine:

   ="Includes: " & Chr(10) & JOIN(Parameters!Agency.Value, ", ")

Reports like this -

Includes:

Lots Of Other Stuff (LOOS), Many More Things Done (MMTD)

2. This statement abbreviates each of the Agency.value that have been identified (otherwise, it goes as original value):

   =iif(Parameters!Agency.Value = "Lots Of Other Stuff (LOOS)", "LOOS",
   iif(Parameters!Agency.Value = "Many More Things Done (MMTD)", "MMTD", Parameters!Agency.Value)))

Report looks like this -

LOOS, MMTD

3. Not sure it's possible to combine them, but I've tried (with error) this statement:

   ="Includes: " & Chr(10) & JOIN(Parameters!Agency.Value, iif(Parameters!Agency.Value = "Lots Of Other Stuff (LOOS)", "LOOS", iif(Parameters!Agency.Value = "Many More Things Done (MMTD)", "MMTD", Parameters!Agency.Value))), ")

Want it to look like this -

Includes:

LOOS, MMTD

not this -

Includes:

Lots Of Other Stuff (LOOS), Many More Things Done (MMTD)

Answer (score 0):

Untested but try this..

```
   ="Includes: " & Chr(10) & 
        JOIN(
             IIF(Parameters!Agency.Value = "Lots Of Other Stuff (LOOS)", "LOOS", 
                 IIF(Parameters!Agency.Value = "Many More Things Done (MMTD)", "MMTD", 
                     Parameters!Agency.Value)),
              ", ")
```

In your attempt you were trying to check is the the JOIN result was a specific value. In the version above we JOIN the list after it has been updated (after the IIF)